# skipping user consent screen oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

Im using oauth2 for my app. Im getting google user profile information. Every thing is working fine. I want to know if there's any way to skip user consent screen? I want to get access token without showing "Allow access" step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

This is what oAuth is all about - you get a token, only after the user has been authenticated and authorized your web-app to use his info.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess you are right. I searched alot and i couldn't find any way to pre-consent or skip user consent step. I have one more question. Is there any way to add app to trusted app list? If yes will it help skipping user consent step? as app is already in trusted app list.

Comment: I have a related question - I have been reading through the OAuth docs and cannot find an answer.  My "application" is a little embedded app that will run on Linux and will read events from my calendar.  I want to hard-code all my info in, since I am the only client.  Because it is embedded, there is no way for any user (just me, really) to interact, so there can be no "user consent screen".  I cannot find anywhere in the OAuth docs how to simply get read access to my own calendar without displaying a consent screen.

Answer (score 2):

No. But you can skip the second time.

I found the good explanation about this question:
[Why does Google OAuth2 re-ask user for permission when i send them to auth url again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508557/why-does-google-oauth2-re-ask-user-for-permission-when-i-send-them-to-auth-url-a)