# Google keeps asking for permission when logging in with play-authenticate

Tags: playframework-2.0, google-oauth, play-authenticate

I am using play-authenticate to provide OAuth access to my web app. It is however annoying that when logging in through google it keeps prompting to grant permission. This dose not occur on the example site https://play-authenticate.herokuapp.com/

My mine.conf looks as follows,

```
 google {
            redirectUri {

                secure=false

            }

            clientId="**********"
            clientSecret="**********"
        }
```

Anyone hava a idea of how to correct this?

In
[Why does Google OAuth2 re-ask user for permission when i send them to auth url again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508557/why-does-google-oauth2-re-ask-user-for-permission-when-i-send-them-to-auth-url-a) the problem is resolved by removing `approval_prompt=force`

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your authorization URL includes parameter 'approval_prompt=force' or 'prompt=consent'? (It may include if you copy-and-pasted from an example). Removing those parameters will result in auto-approval becoming available.