# can't get refresh access token from google in live server

Tags: google-api, laravel-5, google-api-php-client, google-api-console

I am creating a google application to get the user google account data. when i am using the oauth 2 in local with access_type = 'offline', it asks for offline access permission and i can get the refresh access token. But if i use the same code for my live server it didn't ask for offline permission and i can't get the refresh token as well. I am using oriceon oauth 5 package for my laravel application.I did like following

```
    $googleService = OAuth::consumer('Google');
    $googleService->setAccessType('offline');`
```

your Suggestion will helpful for me. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, actually that application stores my access_token in my computer cookies, and it send my key every time using session, so i can't get the refresh token. so what u need to do is, u need to add an option called approval_prompt as force in ur redirect uri like (redirect_uri/approval_prompt=force). It will ask offline access token every time when the application called. check the following link for your reference

[support `approval_prompt: force` to get new `refresh_token](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/124)

[Why does Google OAuth2 re-ask user for permission when i send them to auth url again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508557/why-does-google-oauth2-re-ask-user-for-permission-when-i-send-them-to-auth-url-a)