# Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent screen removal

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api

We looking to change the Drive API, currently, under the Authentication Section we have it checked to Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent screen when users open my application from Google Drive.  We are planning to remove this shortly and want to double check that changing this will not cause our application to go into App Not Verified.  Ideally, this drive app will just handle the redirect then we will handle the scopes.
Thanks

Comment: You may want to try using [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) as also suggested in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815042/android-google-drive-rest-api-skip-consent-screen-hardcoded-accountc).

Comment: After getting in touch with Google the response seemed to say this wouldnt impact our status if we change it.  This has been changed so we will now continue to monitor.