# Don't ask for authorization to Google App a second time

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm using a reverse proxy service, [bitly/oauth2_proxy](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy), in front of a couple websites. Every time a users logs in they must "Allow" access to "x, y, z". I would like to only have users authenticate once, removing the redundant action of clicking "Allow" every time a user logs in.

Is there a way in the Google Developer Console to enable this or do I have to handle this in my authentication handler in my reverse proxy service? If it's in the handler, of my reverse proxy service, where's the documentation that would allow me to add this ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the page I was looking at and found a duplication of my question: [Why does Google OAuth2 re-ask user for permission when i send them to auth url again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508557/why-does-google-oauth2-re-ask-user-for-permission-when-i-send-them-to-auth-url-a)

For those that came for `bitly/oauth2_proxy` you must set the flag `--approval-prompt="auto"` during runtime or in your config.