# Robot Framework api test with OAUTH2 Authorization Request Header

Tags: frameworks, robotframework, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the RequestsLibrary on an api thats using the OAUTH2 authentication.

Authentication is via OAUTH2 with credentials being supplied to the /v1/authtoken endpoint. 
Subsequent calls to the APÍ need to have the token included as a ‘bearer’ in the ‘Authorization’ header of the http requests.

So below is the test case. The error I am getting is:
401 != 200

The credentials work ok in jmeter and a list of accounts is returned. However, I am not able to get the RF script work. Any help will be appreciated.

In the script,

1. Log to Console `${accessToken}` returns the access token: 8ETFXTZOWQLrgsMj7c_KuCEeypdj-eO1r...
2. Log to Console `${token}` returns: Bearer 8ETFXTZOWQLrgsMj7c_KuCEeypdj-eO1r...

```
*** Test Cases ***

Get authToken
    Create Session  hook    http://xxxx.azurewebsites.net  verify=${True}
    ${data}=      Create Dictionary     grant_type=client_credentials     client_id=yyy-zzzz     client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ${headers}=   Create Dictionary      Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    ${resp}=    post request    hook    /v1/authtoken    data=${data}   headers=${headers}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}     200
    Dictionary Should Contain Value     ${resp.json()}  bearer
    ${accessToken}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
    Log to Console        ${accessToken}
    ${Bearer}=      Set Variable   Bearer
    ${token}=       catenate    Bearer    ${accessToken}
    Log to Console     ${token}
    ${headers}=   Create Dictionary   Authorization=${token}
    ${resp1}=     get request       hook    /v1/integration/accounts  headers=${headers}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp1.status_code}    200
    #Log to Console   ${resp1.json()}
```

Comment: @ sandeep  @Bryan    Did you find answer to your question as I am getting same error. kindly share the answer

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Just saw this discussion.... I will try this out.

Comment: Yes, This seems to work for me now. Thanks. 
However, my pure python method to generate the auth2 token is  , I must say much more concise!

Answer (score 1):

I am using OAuth 2.0 authentication as well for my salesforce automation.

**My first answer would be to skip client based authentication and switch to username/password based authentication**

```
      Get authToken by Password Authentication

RequestsLibrary.Create Session  hook    https://<url>/services/oauth2  verify=${True}
${data}=      Create Dictionary     grant_type=password     client_id=1abc    client_secret=2abc    username=test@test.com  password=keypass
${headers}=   Create Dictionary      Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
${resp}=        RequestsLibrary.Post Request    hook    /token    data=${data}   headers=${headers}
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}     200
${accessToken}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
Log to Console        ${accessToken}
```

If you are using client based or web based authentication, there will be a login screen that will be used by the user to enter their username/password to authorise the app to send requests on its behalf. Have a look at these pages for more information as they primarily discuss about using either refresh tokens or skipping the user prompt altogether.

- [Why does Google OAuth2 re-ask user for permission when i send them to auth url again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508557/why-does-google-oauth2-re-ask-user-for-permission-when-i-send-them-to-auth-url-a)
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/785/authenticate-3rd-party-application-with-oauth2

Answer (score 1):

```
I have added the new answer for this question.

RequestsLibrary.Create Session    OA2    <Your Server URL>    verify=${True}
${data}=     Create Dictionary    Token_Name=TestTokenname    grant_type=<grant type>    client_Id=<your Id>     Client_Secret=<Your client secret>    scope=<your scpe>
${headers}=   Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

${resp}=    RequestsLibrary.Post Request    OA2    identity/connect/token    data=${data}    headers=${headers}
BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${resp}
BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${resp.status_code}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${resp.json()}   Testtokenname
${accessToken}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
BuiltIn.Log to Console    ${accessToken}
${token}=    catenate    Bearer    ${accessToken}
BuiltIn.Log to Console    ${token}
${headers1}=  Create Dictionary    Authorization=${token} 

RequestsLibrary.Create Session    GT    <Your Server URL>    verify=${True}        
${resp}=  RequestsLibrary.Get Request  GT    <Your API URL>    headers=${headers1}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```